# How can I retrieve all unique permissions using Azure AD API?

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to get all the unique permissions via API in Azure AD. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-resource-permissions) describes and list all the available claim values, but I am not able to find an API to do the same. Also, are there APIs to assign these permissions to service principles?

I tried going through all the Microsoft graph api list, but not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To grant permissions to the Azure AD Application, you can make use of below [**Microsoft Graph API**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) query:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/ApplicationObjectID

{
"requiredResourceAccess": [
{
"resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
"resourceAccess": [
{
"id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
"type": "Scope"
},
{
"id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
"type": "Scope"
},
{
"id": "7ab1d382-f21e-4acd-a863-ba3e13f7da61",
"type": "Role"
}
]
}
]
}
```

[image]

The API permissions added successfully to the Application like below:

[image]

Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#all-permissions-and-ids) to know the permission IDs.

To fetch the permissions of the Azure AD Application, make use of below query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/ApplicationObjectID/requiredResourceAccess
```

[image]

By using the below query, delegated permissions are displayed:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/ServicePrincipalObjID/oauth2PermissionGrants
```

[image]

By using the below query, application permissions are displayed:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/ServicePrincipalObjID/appRoleAssignments
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=ms-graph#grant-admin-consent-for-delegated-permissions-1)

Comment: thank you for your response. Here the step where you mentioned look for permission id from the doc, I want to automate that. I am looking for an API that would give me the list of all permissions and their IDs. Would you have knowledge on that?

Comment: You have to call two different API to achieve your scenario

Comment: Could you specify which APIs would be those? I notice, that I can get these permissions by specifying an application or service principal id, but those would again be a subset of all the permissions. Which API(s) provide me list of all the permissions?